# Strange behavior with RegOpenKeyEx

Tags: c++, c, windows, registry

In work I encounter a strange behavior of our product, which found can be boiled down to the weird behavior of Windows API RegOpenKeyEx.
Below is my test code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HKEY hk;
    LONG lreturn = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
    TEXT("Software\\Mercury Interactive\\LoadRunner\\Vugen\\Logger\\media"),
    0, 
    KEY_READ, 
    &hk ); 

    if(lreturn==ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        printf("YES!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("NO!\n");
    }
    char a ;
    scanf("%c ", &a);

    return 0;
}
```

On my local machine, the above program prompts "YES," while running on another remote virtual machine it outputs "NO."

On Both machine, registry key "Software\Mercury Interactive\LoadRunner\Vugen\Logger\media" exists under HKEY_CURRENT_USER rather than HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE.

So I am baffled why it ouputs "YES" on local machine? And stranger still, why it behaviors differently on the two machines?
Local machine is Win7 64bit. Remote virtual machine is Win7 32bit. The program is compiled as 32bit.

Answer (score 2):

This sounds a bit like [Registry Virtualization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa965884%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), if the local machine has a entry in the VirtualStore (A previous Create call during development?) the open call will succeed even if the key does not exist under HKLM.

To get to the bottom of this you could run [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx)...

Comment: +1.  It sounds exactly like registry virtualization.  It redirects HKLM queries to a virtual HKCU location for 32-bit processes running on a 64-bit Windows (Vista or later).

Comment: Virtualization is for UAC, Redirection/Reflection for WOW64 IIRC

Comment: @Andres: Maybe this is not related with Registry Virtualization. The  key used by 32bit program on 64bit machine is in a different path. Process Monitor shows the actual path accessed is HKLM\Software\Wow6432Node\Mercury Interactive\LoadRunner\Vugen\Logger\media. This key does exist on local machine. When I delete this key, the output on local machine is "NO!"

Comment: You can use KEY_WOW64_64KEY to disable this behavior, read more about the registry on WOW64 @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that the key does not exist on the remote machine, or you don't have access rights.

Check the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724897%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and the error code it returns.

Comment: According to the OP it shouldn't exist on the local machine (or on the other one). I would double check it if that hasn't been done, though.

Comment: @Alex, it does exist on remote machine. I run this program as admin

Answer (score 0):

Use the `FormatMessage( ... )` function to display a more meaningfull description of the error.

Comment: You don't even need that. It's faster to just print the error message -> copy & paste it in the `Error Lookup` utility in Visual Studio ( `Tools` -> `Error Lookup` ).

Comment: The error message is "The system cannot find the file specified."